# Is there a way to put UIView on top of a swipe action on a tablecell in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I want to do something like this:

[image]

but what I end up is the element getting clipped and being pushed as i swipe left like so:

[image]

Edit:
Here's my code initial code.

Swipe action:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSWipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

   var error: [[String : AnyObject]]
   var cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TabeleViewCell
   error = tableModelValue[5] as! [[String : AnyObject]]

   if(error[0]["value"] as? String != " ") {
     cell.errorView.isHidden = false
     cell.errorText.text = error[0]["value"] as? String
   } else {
     cell.errorView.isHidden = true
   }
   
   let important = importantAction(at: indexPath)
   let details = detailsAction(at: indexPath)
   
   let swipeAction = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [details, important]))

   return swipeAction

}
```

the errorView is the red UIView that appears when the user swipes left.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Would you provide reproducible code example for this?

Comment: @Asperi added code i used for this!

Comment: What if you change the zIndex of the layer of the view?

Comment: tried placing cell.error.layer.zPosition = 999, unfortunately didn't work D: @TamásSengel

Comment: It is not here, your Authorize and Detail buttons must be placed below main cell content in view hierarchy (either in Storyboard, if you designed cell there, or in code, if you added them programmatically).

Comment: hello! the "buttons" are actually UIContextualActions and are then added to swipeAction which is a UISwipeActionsConfiguration, and is a part of a feature of tableviews @Asperi